# How to fix a C# method that produces a result but returns null to the calling method

Tags: c#, json, null

I have this class that, when run in a console app, produces a formatted json string. Now I want to call this method and return the result.

I'm calling it this way var typeRefPath = GetLists.GetTechType(); But it tells me that it is returning null.

What am I doing wrong?

````
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace AutosortLockers
{
    class GetLists
    {
        public static string TechList { get; set; }

        public static string GetTechType()
        {
            // Load categories.json
            JObject catObj = JObject.Load(new JsonTextReader(File.OpenText(Mod.GetModPath() + "/categories.json")));
            // Load techtypes.json
            JObject ttObj = JObject.Load(new JsonTextReader(File.OpenText(Mod.GetModPath() + "/techtypes.json")));

            foreach (var categoriesJson in catObj)
            {
                // Filter variables
                var gameVersions = new HashSet<char> { 'A', '2' };
                var categoryIDs = new HashSet<string> { "metals", "tablets" };
                var useInMod = new HashSet<bool> { true };

                // Right outer join on catObj.  Select all Items[*] array items
                var query = from c in catObj.SelectTokens("Categories[*]").OfType<JObject>()
                                            // Join catObj with ttObj on CategoryID
                                        join t in ttObj.SelectTokens("TechTypes[*]") on (string)c["CategoryID"] equals (string)t["CategoryID"]
                                        // Process the filters
                                        where categoryIDs.Count() > 0 ?
                                        useInMod.Contains((bool)c["UseInMod"])
                                        && gameVersions.Contains((char)c["GameVersion"])
                                        && gameVersions.Contains((char)t["GameVersion"])
                                        && categoryIDs.Contains((string)c["CategoryID"]) :
                                        useInMod.Contains((bool)c["UseInMod"])
                                        && gameVersions.Contains((char)c["GameVersion"])
                                        && gameVersions.Contains((char)t["GameVersion"])
                                        select new
                                        {
                                            CategoryDescription = c["CategoryDescription"],
                                            CategoryID = c["CategoryID"],
                                            TechName = t["TechName"],
                                            TechType = t["TechType"],
                                            TechID = t["TechID"],
                                            GameVersion = t["GameVersion"]
                                        };
                // Materialize the query into a list of results.
                 TechList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query.ToArray(), Formatting.Indented);
            }
            return TechList;
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: It returns `null` because `catObj` has no properties to enumerate through. You never enter your loop, so you never assign a value to `TechList`. Why is `TechList`  static field anyway? It seems like it should be a local variable belonging to the method.

Comment: @Llama the method works correctly. It joins catObj and ttObj on CategoryID.  You may be right about the local vs static. I'll check it out. I'm very inexperienced. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Use a debugger and check if you ever reach by breakpoint:

```
TechList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query.ToArray(), Formatting.Indented);
```

When you don't reach this line, it will use the default value (which is null) since you declared it as static. If you declare it locally (in your method), your IDE should warn you that declared a variable which was potentially never initialized (https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/declaring-and-initializing-variables-in-c).

I guess your query on the json is wrong, but without the data this is impossible to tell.

Comment: your comment made me check my paths. The json files were not found. When I hardcoded the paths the method returns the desired results. Now I have to figure out why the `Mod.GetModPath() + "/categories.json"` is not working. And why the results are not being parsed in the calling method. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score -2):

Try changing the line from

`TechList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query.ToArray(), Formatting.Indented);`

to

`TechList += JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query.ToArray(), Formatting.Indented);`

Comment: Why do you think this helps?

Comment: It is within a for loop, so no matter what data it processes, `TechList` will always store result from the final/last iteration.

Comment: And why do you think that `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(...)` is returning `null`? Isn't it far more likely that `catObj` doesn't contain any properties to enumerate through?

Comment: Agreed with your explanation.